# jquery dynamic content on ie

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem with the site I'm developing. The dynamically loaded div (ajax) is empty in IE9 and works poorly on firefox (php doesn't compile) and I can read the source of my php file in the div.
I've tried a lot of solutions like changing from GET to POST or adding a unique id to the url or making an async request but the content is absolutely empty.  Any ideas? thanks

```
function pageload(hash) {
    if(hash == '' || hash == null)
    {
      document.location.hash = "#php"; // home page
    }

    if(hash)
    {
     getPage();
    }

} 

function getUniqueTime() {
   var time = new Date().getTime();
   while (time == new Date().getTime());
   return new Date().getTime();
}   

function getPage() {
   var str = getUniqueTime();
   console.log(str);
   var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
   $('#content').fadeOut(200);
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php?_=" + str, 
        type: "POST",       
        data: data,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {          
                  $('#content').fadeIn(200);
                  $('#content').html(html);
             }      
    });
}
```

EDIT:

```
   //loader.php
<?
require_once('session.class.php');
require_once('user.class.php');

$se = new session();
$lo = new user();

$se->regenerate();

if(isset($_POST))
{
$alpha = (string) $_POST['page'];

if($alpha == '#php')
{
  include 'homeloader.php';
}

else if($alpha == '#cplus')
{
 include 'cplusloader.php';
}

else if($alpha == '#web')
{
  include 'underloader.php';
}

else if($alpha == '#about')
{
  include 'underloader.php';
}

else if($alpha == '#social')
{
  include 'socialloader.php';
}
  }
else
  $page = 'error';


 echo $page;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//on click of a button:
$("#button").live("click", function(){

   //get you string data
   var str = "test";
   //do new version of ajax
   $.post("loader.php", {str:str}, function(html){
      $('#content').html(html);
   });
});
```

and you dont need to do AJAX method anymore $.post works amazing

Comment: your solution seems to work.. but which is the sent post value?

Comment: the post value is str so u will need to pick it up with $_POST["str"]

Comment: ok.. but how to use it without the button click ?  i'm trying this  $(window).on("load", document, function...)

Comment: take out $("#button").live("click", function(){ and take out the last }); then it will execute on page load, i would do "$(window).load(function(){ " instead

Comment: what version of ie? do you have it in the head of the html?

Comment: ie9 ..Do you mean in the head section of my index.php?

Comment: yeah, you need to place the $(window).load(function(){ where the user is at, so if the user is at the index.php page, then yes. jQuery will run from current location, so yo have to reference the plugins in every page you want it to run.

Comment: usually the `$(function(){ ... })` overload is used, which, if passed a function executes it when the document is *ready* across all current browsers. `$.post` does exactly the same as calling `$.ajax` with type `POST`. It's a shorthand.

Comment: @Relentless thx for all.. i changed from jquery.history.js to jquery.ba-hashchange.js plugin and so my approach to page loading is changed now bye

Answer (score 0):

`php doesn't compile`? `async request`? actually not specifying `ascync: true` the request is executed asyncroniously and in version jQuery 1.8 there is no sync AJAX requests at all. Attach an error handler and you will see that your request probably results an error:

```
    ...
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {          
              $('#content').fadeIn(200);
              $('#content').html(html);
    },
    error: function (a,b) {
      alert('Error!');
    }
    ...
```

Normally AJAX consists of 2 parts - client side and server side. I don't see serverside posted in your question. You have to check both of them. Make a simple `loader.php` returning the string `success` and get rid of all extra get params. First test your php file in browser to be sure that it works. Check FireBug for javascript errors ...

Comment: in my edit i added the php code.. Actually i don't see any error alerts with your code.  My php works fine as it isn't loaded via ajax.. my admin.php page works perfectly

Comment: use `Firefox - FireBug - Scripts tab` - put and break point in success and error handlers - see where it goes when executed. If you don't have it installed (Firebug) ...go to addons and install it - very useful one not just for this case. Try debuging a bit your code and you will understtand what's really happened.

Comment: i solved firefox issue i have a typo error in php tag.. very strange .. sorry